# Remove "age" field or remove requirement of "age" field for Autobiographer badge

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, profile-page, age

I would like the Autobiographer badge, but I don't want to put my age on my profile. I think asking for your age is just a *little* too personal to have on a programming / IT / computer website. At least make it optional for the Autobiographer badge.

Comment: Put in any age, get the badge, remove the age. Profit.

Comment: You forgot the `????` step.

Comment: haha @DeadHead I was thinking the same :)

Comment: I did what Ian describes when I first got on SO, but I eventually lost the badge.  It may behave differently now, however.

Comment: @raven - I think you have to keep your fake age. :(

Comment: Out of curiosity, is it possible to search for the oldest users? (Not as in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=oldest )

Comment: I tried to enter "Information Age", but it wouldn't let me.

Comment: Close voters: don't use "no repro" for a bug that can't be reproduced *because of the way it got fixed*.

Answer (score 22):

Two better options than simply requiring birthdate:

- Accept month and day only. The sites can wish me a happy birthday on the appointed date but demographic stats aren't as complete. On the other hand the demographic stats would likely be more accurate given that users might otherwise enter a false birthdate
- Offer option to hide age. I'm ok with including my information in aggregated calculations, but I don't feel that it's necessary to associate my age with my questions, answers, votes for the whole world to see.

Comment: Hiding the age would be optimal.

Comment: Age discrimination is a reality in this field, and it's darn hard to prove.  Allow the age to be hidden, or for that matter hide it by default.

Answer (score 7):

So yeah - asking for your age is creepy. If you want to share, the field is there - but we don't need to beg for it.

There are other good reasons not to **badge**r folks into sharing a ton of personal details, so as of today [we just ask that you write *something* - anything - that'll introduce you to the community](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit)... and ask for nothing more.

Comment: http://instantrimshot.com

Answer (score 5):

That badge exists so they can gather demographics. They are encouraging you to provide information they can use to tailor the site to the correct audience. If you refuse to give all that information (as is your right) then you are withholding what they need.

So, no, you can't (nor should you) get the badge for *almost* completing the task set out.

I don't have that badge, because I decided I'd rather not provide what they asked for, but I understand that if I don't fulfill the requirements, I therefore don't get the badge.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why it is needed in general for the profile... You could of course ignore the badge and not fill it in...

Answer (score 1):

If you consider how many people are already entering wrong age information, maybe just to get this badge, we could need something to encurage them to correct their mistake.

Therefor I propose this:

- age should still be a required value to earn the badge
- There should be an option to make the age hidden to other users
- someone who has once lied (provided a wrong age) and now provides the correct age, but hides it, should be awarded a new badge for being honest in the end. I leave it up to the native english speakers to think of a nice name for that badge.

*(When the birthdate is changed, I know it is impossible to check programatically if this is a state change from wrong-to-right. It could also be right-to-wrong or wrong-to-wrong, but if the user hides his age, chances are good that it's wront-to-right-transition.)*

Comment: Doesn't this generate a lot of people who enter incorrect ages, and then enter the correct one? Or just enter two incorrect ages? Now they are gaming for two badges.

Comment: @devinb: Yeah, you're right. Didn't think about that, was too tired.

Answer (score 0):

You could always fib if uncomfortable.  There are an amazing amount of 80+ programmers on this site, if we were all being truthful.

Comment: Isn't 30 actually 80 in programmer years?

Comment: (-1) If you want the badge, be honest, if you don't want to be honest, just don't get the badge.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set your birth date to some dummy value e.g. 1920/01/01, then wait few minutes for the Autobiographer badge to arrive, and finally remove birth date.

This way you'll get the badge, and you don't have to set the birth date.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to pick the epoch?