# Deleted questions appearing in related questions box

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, related-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Related questions box show deleted questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3489/related-questions-box-show-deleted-questions)

The Related questions box at the side of a question seems to still display deleted questions.

For example, I see [How did I get a Peer Pressure badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/how-did-i-get-a-peer-pressure-badge-w-o-3-vote) in the box at [Remove age field or remove requirement of age field for Autobiographer Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10188/remove-age-field-or-remove-requirement-of-age-field-for-autobiographer-badge).

But when I go there I get a 404 (I assume that's because the question is deleted.) Is that really the case?

---

Note: it's gone now (see Jeff's answer). But this is a (really minor, doesn't-really-need-to-be-fixed) problem with how the recent questions are designed because it does appear for a short while.

Comment: I see it too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That list is perodically rebuilt as the question is accessed, so over time it should not be a serious issue.

Comment: Uh, kind of hit the update while not seeing that you'd already tagged it.

Comment: YOU ARE FIRED!!