# Why do you ask for 'real name' on Area51?

Tags: discussion, area-51

The autobiographer badge conditions [were recently changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239938/autobiographer-badge-now-only-requires-sharing-what-you-want-with-the-communit) because some fields were a bit too 'personal'; a specific reason in that post is:

> A lot of the fields felt too personal to many people. "Age" and "Real Name" in particular rubbed some people the wrong way as a "requirement" for anything, even something as silly as a badge.

Which is kind of true, and seeing as SE acknowledges this fact, can we get rid of the *mandatory* 'real name' field when committing to a proposal?

I know I can just enter anything, like my username - but I shouldn't have to lie to commit to a proposal I think.

Comment: hmmmm... @ShadowWizard - thanks; didn't see that post!

Comment: I always use my username :)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ sure, that's what I'm here for! ;)